# Mysql function count() counts rows individually

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, rows

I have the following query, where i want to get the total number of rows but this seems to count each individually here is the query and the result

```
SELECT
     COUNT(pc.product_id)
FROM
    products as p
INNER JOIN product_categories as pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id AND pc.subcategory_id IN (77)   
GROUP BY pc.product_id
HAVING COUNT(pc.subcategory_id) = 1
```

### Result is :

COUNT(pc.product_id)

1

1

1

...but it should be

COUNT(pc.product_id)

3

UPDATE

the above query should count the number of products that are get by this query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products as p
INNER JOIN product_categories as pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id AND pc.subcategory_id IN ($sb_2)   
GROUP BY pc.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.subcategory_id) = $sb_count 

$sb_2 = 77,76;
$sb_count = how many values are in $sb_2;

77 and 76 are different subcategories ids but are common for some products
```

If you know another way to count this or to make another query...

Comment: It's the group by. You're grouping by product_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to count rows by the following query.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM (SELECT
    *
FROM
  product_categories WHERE subcategory_id IN (77,76)   
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subcategory_id) = 2) as subc";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
     COUNT(pc.product_id)
FROM
    products as p
INNER JOIN product_categories as pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id AND pc.subcategory_id IN (77)
HAVING COUNT(pc.subcategory_id) = 1
```

Removing the group by should do the trick.

Comment: removing the group by gives '0' rows.

Comment: Well I don't know how your database is setup, but grouping by product_id will always give you 3 rows with 1 count in each row.

Comment: Uh... it's the exact same as your original query without the `GROUP BY` - it should produce the exact same data, just organized differently.